# Cannot Connect to Database Server mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, workbench

I'm trying to connect to mysql workbench but I get the following error

Error Message
Cannot Connect to Database Server

Your connection attempt failed for user 'root' from your host to server at 
127.0.0.1:3306:
  Could not open database.

Please:
 1. Check that mysql is running on server 127.0.0.1

2. Check that mysql is running on port 3306 (note: 3306 is the default, but this can be changed)
3. Check the root has rights to connect to 127.0.0.1 from your address (mysql rights define what clients can connect to the server and from which machines)
4. Make sure you are both providing a password if needed and using the correct 
   password for 127.0.0.1 connecting from the host address you're connecting

When I Test Connection, the parameters are correct, and actually I can enter and manage database in console. 
When I installed Mysql for first time I could enter to Workbench one time and if I closed Workbench I had to restart my PC to connect another time.
I reinstalled 2 or 3 times Mysql server and Workbench and now I cannot connect from Workbench even once.

Comment: Is MySQL installed in your localhost or in a server?

Comment: @bcesars In localhost, but I also tried to connect to a server, and I get the same, when I test de connection it says that parameters are correct but I can't connect. Im new in this, not sure if that is what you meant

Comment: Error message says that ist could not open DATABASE. And you said that you reinstalled mysql. Ist that schema you try to connect to still present?

Comment: @SOehl I left empty the field "Default Schema" , And put a database too but gives me the same message

Comment: if you're trying to connect as root, then please try to connect to schema mysql.

Comment: @SOehl  I made what you said, but shows the same message, In console I can connect and see that schema

Comment: sry, not shure about that. If you can connect by console your server is well configured. If you're using Windows it might be possible that your Windows Firewall ist blocking the Workbench (not the Port!)

Comment: Even I am having the same issue. Initially the connection went through. But after restarting the system, I have started facing this error. Even uninstalling and reinstalling the workbench did'nt help. The connection parameter test passes though!
@Fernando Gonzalez: Were you able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

I faced similar issue and resolved it by following these steps:

1. In the terminal, execute this command
   mysql -u root -p -h localhost -P 3306
2. Enter the password
3. This will be displayed
   Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
   Your MySQL connection id is 18
   Server version: 8.0.16 Homebrew
4. Now do,
   ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'root';
5. Now you should be able to login and connect to DB in the workbench with password 'root'

Comment: This worked!! The key here is mysql_native_password.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it helps anyone, but I had the same problem on windows after updating from MySQL 5.7 to 8.0.

The solution for me was to go to services.msc, stop the MySQL service and start the "MySQL80" service instead.

Then I restarted MySQL Workbench (run as admin) and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

In the run window ( in Windows use windows + r ) and search for **services.msc**

[image]

Now search for **MySQL 80**

[image]

On the left hand, you can see an option to **restart** click on that wait for a few seconds to complete and your MySQL should now be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

This solved it for me (MAC OS)

1. Open MySQL from System Preferences > MySQL
2. Click 'Stop MySQL Server' if the server is running
3. Select 'Initialize Database'
4. Type your new password.
5. Choose 'Use legacy password'
6. Start the Server again.
7. Now connect the MySQL Workbench

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that You have Downloaded MySQl server while dowloading MySQl workbench from MySQl installer (if you have checked Custom download)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue a few days ago. As I could see in the original question, there has been **multiple MySQL installation** on the same computer - the same flow I tried after failing in the first attempt.

In the case we are trying to reinstall MySQL, we should be aware of remaining hidden files after MySQL has been uninstalled for the first time. In order to remove them all (and make one successful installation), we should:

1. Make hidden files visible on your computer ([instructions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/view-hidden-files-and-folders-in-windows-10-97fbc472-c603-9d90-91d0-1166d1d9f4b5#:%7E:text=Open%20File%20Explorer%20from%20the,folders%2C%20and%20drives%20and%20OK.))
2. Delete all files related to MySQL after choosing uninstalling of the MySQL (I had to check C://ProgramData hidden folder)
3. Try a new installation

I think that during the first installation, I didn't have all required dependencies on the computer (for example Python) and the installation failed. After installing it, uninstalling the MySQL, and taking steps from above, I finally managed to run it successfully :)

I hope this could help someone! :)